# Kendo UI MVC Grid date editor template not displaying value from grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following view.

```
@using BecomingAKendoUISamurai.ViewModels

<h2>Step 21 MVC Grid CRUD</h2>

<br/>

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SamuraiViewModel>()
    .Name("SamuraiGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Bound(m => m.Id).Hidden();
      columns.Bound(m => m.FirstName);
      columns.Bound(m => m.LastName);
      columns.Bound(m => m.RankId).ClientTemplate("#=Rank#");
      columns.Bound(m => m.DateOfBirth).Width(125);
      columns.Bound(m => m.DateOfDeath).Width(125);
      columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(200);
  })
  .DataSource(source => source
    .Ajax()
    .Sort(s => s.Add(p => p.LastName).Ascending())
    .PageSize(5)
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(m => m.Id);
    })
    .Create(create => create.Action(MVC.Home.ActionNames.CreateSamuraiMvc, MVC.Home.Name))
    .Read(read => read.Action(MVC.Home.ActionNames.ReadSamuraiMvc, MVC.Home.Name))
    .Update(update => update.Action(MVC.Home.ActionNames.UpdateSamuraiMvc, MVC.Home.Name))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action(MVC.Home.ActionNames.DestroySamuraiMvc, MVC.Home.Name))

)
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)) //PopUp and InCell 
.Sortable()
.Pageable(p => p.PageSizes(new int[]{2,4,6}))
.Filterable()
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
  )
```

Using the following View Model

```
namespace BecomingAKendoUISamurai.ViewModels
{
  public class SamuraiViewModel : IMappableViewModel<SamuraiViewModel, Samurai>
  {
    #region Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Rank")]
    [UIHint("Rank")]
    public int RankId { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Ranks { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    [UIHint("DateOfBirthDate")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Date of Death")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MMMM dd yyyy}")]
    [UIHint("DateOfDeathDate")]
    public DateTime DateOfDeath { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public SamuraiViewModel()
    {
        Ranks = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public SamuraiViewModel(Samurai samurai)
    {
        FromEntity(samurai);
    }
    #endregion

    #region IMappableViewModel

    public void FromEntity(Samurai entity)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Samurai, SamuraiViewModel>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.RankId, m => m.MapFrom(e => e.Rank))
            .ForMember(vm => vm.Rank, m => m.MapFrom(e => e.Rank.ToString()));

        Mapper.Map(entity, this);
    }

    public Samurai ToEntity()
    {
        var entity = new Samurai();
        Mapper.CreateMap<SamuraiViewModel, Samurai>()
            .ForMember(e => e.Rank, src => src.MapFrom(vm => vm.RankId));

        Mapper.Map(this, entity);
        return entity;
    }
    #endregion

    public string JsonRanks
    {
        get { return Ranks.ConvertToJson(); }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the following editor template

```
@model DateTime?

@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
            .Name("DateOfBirth")
            .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
            .Value(Model == null ? DateTime.Now : @Model)
)
```

Calling the controller's read method

```
public virtual JsonResult ReadSamuraiMvc([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
  return Json(GetSamuraiViewModels().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
private List<SamuraiViewModel> GetSamuraiViewModels()
{
  var viewModel = new List<SamuraiViewModel>();

  var samurais = samuraiService.ReadSamurai().ToList();
  if (samurais.Any())
  {
    samurais.ForEach(s => viewModel.Add(new SamuraiViewModel(s)));
  }
  return viewModel;
}
```

I can see all the data in the grid. For example row 1 has:
"Hatori" "Hanzo" "Grand Master" "03/15/1541" "April 16 1563" Edit Delete

When I click the Edit button, first name, last name and Rank all have the values defined in the row, but Date of Birth and Date of Death are both empty.

How do I fix this?

I have tried using inline and popup mode and get the same results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried taking the ui hint off the date of birth property and tried to use the default date time picker that is supplied with the mvc wrappers. Alternatively try using kendo().datepickerfor(model) this will bind the value for you. Also why not check to see if model.hasvalue if using a nullable datetime

Comment: When I remove the UIHint from the model,  I get the default dateTime picker editor, but it is also empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using DatePickerFor:

```
@model DateTime?
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m)
      .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
)
```

Comment: This is what I had tried originally, but it wasn't working. Then I found one row where DateOfBirth actually had data in it, which I found completely odd. So I changed the DateOfBirth and DateOfDeath for Hatori Hanzo (in my example above from "03/15/1541" "April 16 1563" to "03/15/1941" and "April 16 1963" and when I refreshed the grid and pressed the edit button the data was there. There seems to be an issue with allowing values before a certain date. Anything before 1/1/1900 isn't shown in edit mode. Whats up with that?

Comment: I added .Min(new DateTime(1000,1,1)) to the Date.cshtml file and now I see all my dates. I started remembering that the default min for datepickers is 1/1/1900 and hence why it wasn't displaying dates before that.